# Laplace transform of $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-2t}}{t-7}$

Tags: laplace-transform

How am I supposed to find the Laplace transform of
$$\frac{e^{-2t}}{t-7}$$

I tried to use the fact that
$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{ct}f(t)\}=F(s-c)$$
but I can't find a Laplace transform of
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{t-7}$$

Comment: @Moo Yes, unfortunately, I'm sure.

Comment: Looks like: $\pi  G_{2,3}^{2,1}\left(7 (s+2)\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{2} \\
 0,0,\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$ Solved with Mathematica `12.1.1`

Comment: Using the substitution $t \leftrightarrow t-7$, it should be clear that we're dealing with [exponential integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). So, there is no elementary closed form for this Laplace transform.